# Moving a Subdirectory folder and its file to a new partition

Tags: filesystem

Please take a look into my partition :)
I still don't know how to move the folder that mounted on old partition

[this is the screenshot](http://imageshack.com/a/img856/8600/g86q.png)

I've to insert a new HDD to it, so the folder /media/samba_disk_1/data/lrn and its old data still there :)

Please help me, I'm sorry if my english is so bad t(^_^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a new directory to use as the mount point for the new harddrive.

`mkdir /media/newhdd/`

Use `df -h` to determine the name of the new HDD, for your setup it should be `/dev/sdc1`, **but be sure before proceeding**.

Mount the drive to the directory you just created: `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/newhdd`

Then `cp` over the files:

`cp -a /media/samba_disk_1/data/lrn /media/newdd`

Don't copy and paste this because you may need to make small changes to the commands.

Comment: thank you very much sir :) this is explained me well enough, I won't copy & paste this ;)

btw, /media/samba_disk_1/data is shared to windows OS with domain name \\vault\lrn :)

\\vault\lrn\ = /media/samba_disk_1/data/lrn

can I locate lrn folder after it moved to a new partition? :)

I meant, /media/samba_disk_1/data = \\vault in windows network :)

I'm using samba server to shared this linux to windows :)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a ton of ways to do this.  My suggestion would be top open a terminal window <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and enter the following code

```
cp -a /media/samba_disk_1/data/lrn /this/is/the/new/path/lrn
```

This will copy file the files to a new partition, but not remove the old files so that you can verify that all are in place before you remove the disk.

Comment: hhehe thank you very much for your answer sir :) yeah, it's great to backup some files first :)